# Component which wraps template in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to create directive (or component) in Angular2 which wraps template with `<div>`

I have template:

```
<table [wrapDirective]  class="table" border="1" >
   <!-- some content -->
</table>
```

And I would like to get somethink like:

```
<div class="wrap-directive" >
    <table class="table" border="1" >
        <!-- some content -->
    </table>
</div>
```

So in angular1 it would be something like this

```
angular.element(element).replaceWith('<div>' + element + '</div>');
```

---

I could use @Component but `<ng-content>` used in template
is rendering to

```
<div class="wrap-directive" >
    <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

Without `table` tag.

---

Another idea was to use @Directive with asterisk `*` sign like `*ngIf` but I don't know how I can use `TemplateRef` or `ViewContainerRef` to extend somehow template.

In sources I found this:

```
 this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
```

But how can I use it to wrap template?